# ***Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'no object at index 77 in section at index 0'

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I am getting following error

> ***Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'no object at index 77 in
>   section at index 0'

This was happening because I am having tabbarcontrollers 2 controller using NSFetchRequestController with same Entity object being used in their root controllers. So both are always active and not one at a time.

Now in my background I take all these objects and send to server to get some info and update back.

But I start getting the above highlighted error as index path of one is not matched with one controller due to its implementation and hence crashed app with exception.

I fixed this as workaround given by putting following code, but this slows my app , is there any more feasible solution.

Also note the viewdidload is not called where we set the fetchresultcontroller object to nil as both are root controller of two tabs.

```
PhoneNumber *phoneMO  = nil;
    if ([[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count] > [indexPath section]){
        id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]];
        if ([sectionInfo numberOfObjects] > [indexPath row]){
            phoneMO = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are any other threads modifying the contents of the `fetchedResultsController` object? Have you tried printing the contents? Also, put the code in question in a try/catch block and examine the objects at runtime in the debugger.

Comment: Hi John, I am checking that that code crashes because I am displaying all the contacts from contact  table in one view controller of tab  in perform fetch with 10 batch size, but the other controller although i am showing the same data in other controller, i break that 1500+ contacts in pieces and send to server to sync in multiple service calls ,...

Comment: so when the server returns the data for each service response the updating is happened accordingly over the main thread only in the Core data update. but may be the two controller may not get that items that is updated as its received in pieces and by that time core data may not have fetched the item , also may have fetched the item but the update call is for some other item.

Comment: Why would `numberOfRowInSection` not match the number of objects returned by the FRC?

Comment: I am not sure about this but when I added the code of looping to check if index path is valid world but slowed performance. I think because the first controller is loading data in batched however the another controller even doing do same is getting conflicted as the data that is synced with server is split into smaller array by first fetching all data in equal parts except last chunk and then checking with server.

Comment: Can you help me how can I send the data in background and update in chunks in core data. I am doing a contact sync to check if it's under my system. If the number is there then I have to go back in core data and update the same. Also in similar manner I want my UI also to be notified so I preferred fetch result as it does smart updating job